# Equality involving expectation on 1D random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

> Suppose $S_n$ is a symmetric random walk on the non-negative integers, and that $0$ is a reflecting state. Specifically, the transition probabilities are $p(0,1) = 1$ and $p(i,i\pm1) = \frac{1}{2}$. Let, $V_n$ denote the number of visits to state $0$ up until time $n$. Prove that for all $n \geq 1$,
>
> $$ E_0[V_{n-1}] = E_0[S_n] - 1 $$
>
> where the subscript means $0$ is the initial state.

We can write $V_{n-1}$ as a sum of indicator functions, $V_{n-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\chi_{\{S_k = 0\}} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\chi_{\{S_k = 0\}} - \chi_{\{S_0 = 0\}}$. Then, taking expectations,

$$ E_0[V_{n-1}] = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}P_0(S_k = 0) - \underbrace{P_0(S_0 = 0)}_{1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}P_0(S_k = 0) - 1$$

So it looks like we need to show that, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}P_0(S_k = 0) = E_0[S_n] = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty kP_0(S_n = k)$. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: In case the notation isn't familiar, the subscript implies a conditional probability, $E_0[V_n] = E[V_n | V_0 = 0]$

Comment: By definition $S_1 = 1 $ with probability 1, and when $n=2$, we have $\mathbb{P}(S_2 = 0) = 1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}(S_2 = 2) = 1/2$, and hence $\mathbb{E}(S_2)  = 1$. On the other hand $V_2 = \chi_{S_1 = 0} + \chi_{S_2 = 0} =  \chi_{S_2 = 0}$ (since $S_1 = 1$ a.s.), and hence $\mathbb{E}(V_2) = \mathbb{P}(S_2 = 0) = 1/2$ . So, the claimed equality does not hold for $n=2$. Am I missing something ?

Comment: The problem statement has been fixed. It looks like there was an indexing mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can show the statement by induction on $n$. It can be checked by hand for $n =1$ and $n=2$.

Now assume $n>2$ and that the claim holds for all $ k < n$. Let's prove for $k = n$.

We can write $V_{n-1} = V_{n-2} + \chi_{ \{S_{n-1} = 0 \}}$, and hence
$$
\mathbb{E} V_{n-1} = \mathbb{E} V_{n-2} + \mathbb{P}(S_{n-1} = 0) = \text{(apply the induction)} = \mathbb{E} S_{n-1} - 1 + \mathbb{P}(S_{n-1} = 0).
$$
Thus, all we are left to show is 
$$
\mathbb{E} S_{n} = \mathbb{E} S_{n-1} + \mathbb{P} (S_{n-1} =0).
$$

To prove the latter, and hence complete the induction step, observe that
$$
S_{n} = S_{n-1} + X_{n},
$$
where $X_{n} = 1 $ if $S_{n-1} = 0$ and  $\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = \pm 1 |S_{n-1} \neq 0) = \frac {1}{2}$. Hence,
$$
\mathbb{E} S_{n} = \mathbb{E} S_{n-1} + \mathbb{P} (S_{n-1} =0) + \mathbb{E}(X_{n}|S_{n-1} \neq 0) .
$$
But the last expectation is 0, since the event $S_{n-1} \neq 0$ is independent of $X_{n}$ (we have a random walk). Hence we are done.

Comment: I'm not sure why the last statement is true. I can see why $S_{n-2}$ would be independent of $X_{n-1}$. But from $S_{n-1} = S_{n-2} + X_{n-1}$, shouldn't $S_{n-1}$ be dependent on $X_{n-1}$?

Comment: thanks for noticing that. It's a typo in the index, $S_{n-1}$ should be $S_{n-2}$. We're adding $X_{n-1}$ to $S_{n-2}$. I'll correct it now.

Comment: OK, I corrected the indices now in the post.